# Coseparators are discrete spaces with at least two elements. Stuck with the proof.

Tags: category-theory

I have the following problem, trying to prove that the coseparators are exactly the maps to an indiscrete space with at least two points.

I'll try to sketch where I am stuck. First of all, I call a coseparator any element $H\in|\mathcal{C}|$ for which $\forall A,B\in |\mathcal{C}|,\forall f\neq g\in\hom_{\mathcal{C}}(A,B),\exists h\in\hom_{\mathcal{C}}(B,H)$ such that $h\circ f\neq h\circ g$.\

$\Leftarrow$ is okay: take any indiscrete structure $(X,\xi_{\text{ind}})$ with $\#X\geq 2$. Then exist at least $x_1\neq x_2$ in $X$. Suppose now that $f\neq g\in\hom_{\mathcal{C}}((A,\eta_1),(B,\eta_2))$. Then there exists an $a\in A$ such that $f(a) \neq g(a)$. Define
$$\begin{array}{llll}
 h:  & (B,\eta_2)     & \longrightarrow & (X,\xi_{\text{ind.}}) \\ 
   & f(a)        & \mapsto     & x_1          \\ 
   & f(b)        & \mapsto     & x_2          \\ 
   & \text{everything else} & \mapsto     & \text{e.g. }x_1
\end{array}$$
Then this is a morphism, because $(X,\xi_{\text{ind.}})$ is indiscrete, and for $a\in A$
$$(h\circ f) (a) = h(f(a)) = x_1\neq x_2 = h(g(a)) = (h\circ g)(a)$$
So as mappings, $h\circ f\neq h\circ g$. Because this is true $\forall f\neq g\in\hom_{\mathcal{C}}(A,B)$, $(X,\xi_{\text{ind.}})$ is a coseparator.

Now for $\Rightarrow$, and here is where it gets tricky. Supose that $(X,\xi)$ is a coseparator.

- Suppose that $X = \{x\} $. Then $\forall a\in A: h\circ f(a) = x = h\circ g(a)$, because there are simply not enough points. This yields a contradiction, so $\#X\geq 2$.
- But here is where I got stuck: I still need to prove that $\xi$ is indiscrete, and here is where I have no clue anymore.

Does anybody see a simple argument why this should be so? I'm thinking in the direction of a contraposition proof. Something in the line of: if $\xi$ is not indiscrete, there exists a map that is no morphism. Since all constant functions are morphisms, this map cannot be constant. But then I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You skipped an important part in the backwards direction: the $h$ you defined must be an arrow in the category (of topological spaces), i e. must be continuous, which is now immediate since $X$ is indiscrete.

Note that if $X\subseteq Y$ and $X$ is a coseparator, then so is $Y$.
So, the statement is not true in this form, the criteria should be that $X$ *contains* an indiscrete subspace of $2$ points.

For that, let $B=\{b_1,b_2\}$ be the indiscrete space, and consider the constant maps $c_1,c_2:B\to B$. By hypothesis there's a continuous $h:B\to X$ that distinguishes $c_1$ and $c_2$, hence $b_1$ and $b_2$ by $x_1:=h(b_1)\ne h(b_2)=:x_2$.
Now if $U$ is an open set in $X$ that contains, say, $x_1$, then $h^{-1}(U)$ is open in $B$ and contains $b_1$. Since $B$ is indiscrete, it must also contain $b_2$, that is, $x_2=h(b_2)\in U$ as well.

Comment: Thanks, I think that I indeed got stuck on the part that X should contain an indiscrete subspace of two points instead of being one. Now it's clear to me, thanks!